# Write a function that rotates an array using .pop and .splice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function that takes two arguments. It will modify the array(are) by popping an element and splicing it at the start of the array. It should be repeated num times.  My attempt so far:

```js
function rotate(arr, num) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i<num){
        arr.pop();
        arr.splice(0, 0, arr.pop());
        i++;
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(rotate(["Harry","Sarah","Oscar","Tina"],2));
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Each call to `arr.pop` removes the last element; you call it twice each iteration.

Comment: @mexicanChica added an answer only with `splice` eveb without loop and `pop`, please check :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array::pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes and returns the removed element. You need to use it only once.

As @Xufox correctly mentions

> Usually this is done with arr.unshift(arr.pop()); I’m not sure why OP  needs to use splice here…

```js
function rotate(arr, num) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i<num){
        arr.unshift(arr.pop());
        i++;
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(rotate(["Harry","Sarah","Oscar","Tina"],2));
```

Comment: Usually this is done with `arr.unshift(arr.pop())`; I’m not sure why OP needs to use `splice` here…

Answer (score 0):

`pop`will remove the last entry of your array and return it. When doing it twice, you loose an entry

```js
function rotate(arr, num) {
    var i = 0;
    while (i<num){
        var x = arr.pop();
        arr.splice(0, 0, x);
        i++;
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(rotate(["Harry","Sarah","Oscar","Tina"],2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of telling us what the function does right now, would you explain in general terms what the function should do? Or what result do you expect from the array in the example?

I see a couple of things:

1. In line 4 you are using `arr.pop()`. This is removing one item from the array and not placing it anywhere. Therefore, your array has one less item.
2. You are calling `arr.pop()` one more time so you are removing yet one more item from the array.
3. Instead of `splice(0,0...)` you could use `unshift()`. This will add an item to the beginning of the array. (Oposite of `push()`)
4. Do you really need to pass and argument that tells how many times should the array rotate? Could you use for your purposes the lenght of the array?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, why you need `pop()` and `loop`, simply twice `splice()` is enough.

```
arr.splice(0,0, ...arr.splice(arr.length-num));
```

```js
function rotate(arr, num) {
   arr.splice(0,0, ...arr.splice(arr.length-num));
   return arr;
}

var arr =["Harry","Sarah","Oscar","Tina"];
rotate(arr, 2);
console.log(arr);
```